# Can't figure out what's causing problems

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I recently asked a question on how I'd set up a cross server bot with per server commands. Someone said I'd be able to using quick.db, then put this code in his answer:

```
client.on("message", message => {
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    if(command == "setautorole"){
        let roleName = args.slice(0).join(" ");
        let role = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name == roleName).catch(message.reply("Couldn't find that role"),
        db.set(`autorole_${message.guild.id}`, role.id)
    }
    if(command == "unsetautorole"){
        db.delete(`autorole_${message.guild.id})
    }
    if(command == "setwelcomechannel"){
        let channelName = args.slice(0).join(" ");
        let channel = message.guild.channels.find(channel => channel.name == channelName).catch(message.reply("Couldn't find that channel")
        db.set(`welcomechannel_${message.guild.id}`, channel.id)
    }
    if(command == "unsetwelcomechannel"){
        db.delete(`welcomechannel_${message.guild.id})
    }
})
client.on("guildMemberAdd", member => {
    let roleId = db.get(`autorole_${member.guild.id}`);
    if(roleId) member.addRole(roleId).catch(console.error);
    let channelId = db.get(`welcomechannel_${member.guild.id}`);
    if(channelId) channel = member.guild.channels.get(channelId).catch(console.error);
    if(channel) channel.send("x")
})
```

The problem is, is that I get a whole lot of errors. https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhKHx.jpg

Where and what would I need to put to fix said errors?

Comment: You need to learn the basic syntax of the language you're trying to use; I'd recommend a tutorial.

Comment: Also please provide a question title that truly describes your problem.  Besides providing you help, one of the purposes of this site is to provide help to those in the future who may have similar problems.  To do so, the questions need to get indexed by Google in the appropriately

Comment: @GeorgeJempty yes, I do apologize. I just don't know a better way to put it. Will keep in mind in the future. <3

Comment: Not to be harsh, but not knowing a better way to phrase your question is a sure sign that you hardly even know what the problem is.

Comment: @GeorgeJempty Yes, I'm new to js/node.js/etc. and I'm taking this as a learning experience. So when VScode says stuff like "10 problems" I don't know any better way to phrase. Either way have a good night friend. <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
client.on("message", message => {
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    if(command == "setautorole"){
        let roleName = args.slice(0).join(" ");
        let role = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name == roleName).catch(message.reply("Couldn't find that role"))
        db.set(`autorole_${message.guild.id}`, role.id)
    }
    if(command == "unsetautorole"){
        db.delete(`autorole_${message.guild.id}`)
    }
    if(command == "setwelcomechannel"){
        let channelName = args.slice(0).join(" ");
        let channel = message.guild.channels.find(channel => channel.name == channelName).catch(message.reply("Couldn't find that channel"))
        db.set(`welcomechannel_${message.guild.id}`, channel.id)
    }
    if(command == "unsetwelcomechannel"){
        db.delete(`welcomechannel_${message.guild.id}`)
    }
})
client.on("guildMemberAdd", member => {
    let roleId = db.get(`autorole_${member.guild.id}`);
    if(roleId) member.addRole(roleId).catch(console.error);
    let channelId = db.get(`welcomechannel_${member.guild.id}`);
    if(channelId) channel = member.guild.channels.get(channelId).catch(console.error);
    if(channel) channel.send("x")
})
```

Comment: This fixes the formatting issues - may not fix the functionality but that's not the question here.

Comment: Thanks, someone gave it to me so hopefully it works.

Answer (score -1):

at line 18 you forgot to close template string :)

Comment: Could you post the fixed code please? I don't know what you mean. Sorry.

Comment: you forgot to use the back-tick ` to close template string, just before the parenthesis,

line 26 as well